Want to give project edit permission to project user group user if he/she is project manager of that project odoo17
Default odoo project user have only read permission given. But I want to give project edit permission if any user from project user group have project manager of that project.
Currently:
access_project_project, project.project, project.model_project_project,
project.group_project_user,1,0,0,0

My attempt in project_security.xml :
<!-- Record Rule: Allow editing a project if the user is the project manager -->
    <record id="project_manager_edit_own_project" model="ir.rule">
        <field name="name">Project Manager Edit Own Project</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="project.model_project_project"/>
        <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('project.group_project_user'))]"/>
        <field name="domain_force">[('user_id', '=', user.id)]</field>
        <field name="perm_read" eval="1"/>
        <field name="perm_write" eval="1"/>
        <field name="perm_create" eval="0"/>
        <field name="perm_unlink" eval="0"/>
    </record>

But my above attempt is not working as expected.
Thanks in advance
